# MySQL Setting local variable inside update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query inside a stored procedure:

```
SET @myVar = '';

UPDATE `my_table` t1
SET 
    t1.field1 = CASE
        WHEN
            -- set @myVar to 'one' when this exists is true
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM `table2` t2
                WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1
            ) OR
           -- set @myVar to 'two' when this exists is true 
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM `table3` t3
                WHERE t1.field1 = t3.field1
            )
            THEN FALSE
        ELSE
            TRUE
    END,
    t1.field3 = CASE
        WHEN
            @myVar = 'one'
            THEN 'okay'
        WHEN
            @myVar = 'two'
            THEN 'not okay'
        ELSE
            'netural'
    END
WHERE t1.field5 = 'value';
```

Is there a way I can set some flag value ('one', 'two', etc...) in a local variable when first or second `EXISTS` condition is true in the `CASE` clause for first `set`. Then I want to use that flag value to set another field.

Is something like this possible? I have searched for while but can't seem to get a sufficient solution to this issue.

**EDIT**: Added comments for where the session/local var should change.

Comment: Sample input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: if you are i a stored procedure set the sessoin varable before the update

Comment: @nbk. That is not quite what I am looking for. I am more looking more for a way to change the value of the local/session variable inside an update query. I hope that clarifies my intentions a bit more.

Comment: @Tim. It's more about whether this something that is possible. I don't know how relevant a sample data would be here.

Comment: @user3303411 . . . Even if you could do this, I don't think that MySQL guarantees the order of evaluation of `set` statements, so there would not be a guarantee that the variable was set before it was used.

Comment: @Gordon. Actually MySQL guarantee's order when a single table is updated. Although this is not SQL standard. `Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right.`

Comment: @user3303411 . . . I have always found that "generally" in the documentation to be disconcerting.  Either you can rely on the order or you cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This select query gives you an 1 as answer and sets @myvar to one

```
SELECT IF(IF(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `df` t3 WHERE 1 = 1), @myVar :='one',0) = 'one',1,0);
SELECT @myVar;
```

So try

```
UPDATE `my_table` t1
SET 
    t1.field1 = CASE
        WHEN
            IF(IF(            
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM `table2` t2
                WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1
            ), @myVar :='one',0) = 'one',1,0) OR
           IF(IF( 
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM `table3` t3
                WHERE t1.field1 = t3.field1
            ), @myVar :='two',0) = 'one',1,0)
            THEN FALSE
        ELSE
            TRUE
    END,
    t1.field3 = CASE
        WHEN
            @myVar = 'one'
            THEN 'okay'
        WHEN
            @myVar = 'two'
            THEN 'not okay'
        ELSE
            'netural'
    END
WHERE t1.field5 = 'value';
```

It doesn't give an error, but without data, you must test it yourself

And i am not sure if the session variable has an vqalue. like i said no data.

But still set the session varoable before hand, it doewsn't make sense doiung it in the update statement.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I was thinking of a similar way of doing this, but it seems "hacky". I guess at point one should take a second look at the design itself to see if a better approach is not available.

Comment: The problem is, that nobody exactly knows, how everything works. I personally think that it must be deterministic and that mysql works everything from strat tp the the end, but optimization could bring other results, but try it please, to see if it works.,

Comment: Your query works just fine in MySQL v8 community ed.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to be certain of the successful completion of this query using variables the way you want to as MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of `SET` evaluation in an `UPDATE` query ("generally" != "guaranteed"). The safest solution is to repeat your `EXISTS` clauses:

```
UPDATE `my_table` t1
SET 
    t1.field1 = CASE
        WHEN
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM `table2` t2
                WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1
            ) OR
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM `table3` t3
                WHERE t1.field1 = t3.field1
            )
            THEN FALSE
        ELSE
            TRUE
    END,
    t1.field3 = CASE
        WHEN
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM `table2` t2
                WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1
            )
            THEN 'okay'
        WHEN
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM `table3` t3
                WHERE t1.field1 = t3.field1
            )
            THEN 'not okay'
        ELSE
            'netural'
    END
WHERE t1.field5 = 'value';
```

The optimiser should be smart enough to realise that the subqueries are being used more than once and re-use the result.

Comment: You make a valid point. If it is not guaranteed then it should not be relied upon, especially if it goes against standards. Makes migrating to a different system that much more difficult. Thanks.